# Disable Settings access in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, default-settings

In Windows 10, we can access the Settings app by pressing the Windows + I shortcut keys, or clicking the Start button and clicking the Settings icon.
Is there a way to disable the Settings keyboard shortcut and remove the Settings icon from Start Menu?

To clarify, I don't want to lock the application itself, I just want to remove the Settings icon in the Start menu and when users press WinKey+I, nothing will happen.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Comment: Always glad to help!

Comment: Update: I find a new feature introduced in Windows 10 Creators Update, which allows to hide all pages in the Settings app. http://winaero.com/blog/hide-settings-pages-windows-10/  This allows me to block users from making changes in the Settings app.

Comment: Good find!  Please keep in mind that once you configure those Group Policies within Windows 10 Version 1703, it will block *all* users from utilizing whatever you hide from the `Settings` app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the Settings icon from Start, do the following:

1. Press <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
2. Navigate through **Personalization** > **Start** and on the bottom-right select **Choose which folders appear on Start**

   [image: Choose which folders appear on Start]
3. In the subsequent window, toggle **Settings** to **Off**

   [image: Settings Off]

Regarding the ability to disable <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, that is a bit more complicated.  If that is the *only* Windows key combination you want to disable, you would probably need to consider software like **AutoHotkey** in order to do it:

> AutoHotkey (AHK) is a free, open-source macro-creation and automation software for Windows that allows users to automate repetitive tasks. It is driven by a scripting language that was initially aimed at providing keyboard shortcuts, otherwise known as hotkeys, that over time evolved into a full-fledged scripting language. And if you're really interested, here's a great video about it [here](https://youtu.be/lIFE7h3m40U?t=2m50s).
>
> You can use AutoHotkey to:
>
> - Automate almost anything by sending keystrokes and mouse clicks.
>     You can write a mouse or keyboard macro by hand or a macro recorder.
> - Remap keys and buttons on your keyboard, joystick, and mouse.
> - Create hotkeys for keyboard, joystick, and mouse. Essentially any key, button or combination can become a hotkey.
> - Expand abbreviations as you type them. For example, typing "btw" can automatically produce "by the way".
> - Retrieve and change the clipboard's contents.
> - Convert any AHK script into an executable file that can be run on computers where AutoHotkey is not installed.
> - Don't know where to start or how to fix your script? Join the friendly AutoHotkey community and ask for help

([Source](https://autohotkey.com/))

Comment: Follow your instructions and successfully removed the Settings icon. But I don't know how to use AutoHotkey to disable WIN+I shorcut keys. Is there other ways? such as map the WIN+I keys so it do nothing?

Comment: AutoHotkey should be able to do that.  If necessary, their support forums can help guide you.  If you don't mind me asking, why are you trying to disable the keyboard shortcut, also?  Keep in mind that you could right-click the `Start` button and still see the menu you see after pressing Windows key plus X, so disabling the Windows key may still be a viable option for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to disable a specific combination. But if you edit the registry you can accomplish part of what you need.

1. Type  Open Registry Editor by typing regedit in RUN or Start search box and pressing Enter.
2. Now go to following key:

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
3. In right-side pane, create a new DWORD NoWinKeys and set its value to 1
4. Make logoff, do a new login and no WIN + any key will work any more.

To re-enable WIN + hotkeys in the future, you can delete the DWORD NoWinKeys created in step 3 or simply give it the value 0 and restart.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! But it also disables the WIN+X keys that I want to keep. I just want to disable WIN+I shortcut key.